# Can use raw sockets to bring broadband Internet?

Tags: c#, sockets

Guys.

I want to calculate Internet broadband and local network broadband separately.For this reason, I think I could use raw socket to get all packet traffic and with the destination address and source address in the IP header I recognize the this packet is internet packet or local packet or BroadCast and ....

Then, I can add to the length of each packet to a Variable separately.

Do you think is it true????

this is my program:

```
    static Stopwatch Time = new Stopwatch();
    static IPSegment ip;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double SumInternet = 0;
        double LocalUsage = 0;
        Time.Start();
        IPAddress MyIp = NetworkManagement.GetIPAddress();
        ip = new IPSegment(MyIp.ToString(), NetworkManagement.GetSubnetMask(MyIp).ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
        Console.Write(" ------------------------------- \n| IP Information :  {0} \n| BroadCast: {1} \n| BroadcastAddress: {1} \n| NetworkAddress: {2} \n| NumberOfHosts: {3}\n|\n", MyIp.ToString(), ip.BroadcastAddress.ToIpString(), ip.NetworkAddress.ToIpString(), ip.NumberOfHosts.ToIpString());
        foreach (uint host in ip.Hosts())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("| " + host.ToIpString());
        }
        Console.WriteLine(" -------------------------------");
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
        Console.WriteLine("");

        NetworkManagement.SetHosts(ip);

        Socket sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Raw, ProtocolType.IP);
        sock.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP, SocketOptionName.HeaderIncluded, true);
        sock.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP, SocketOptionName.PacketInformation, true);


        Console.WriteLine("IP Address: {0} is binding . . . \n", MyIp);
        sock.Bind(new IPEndPoint(MyIp, 0));

        byte[] outValue = new byte[4] { 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        byte[] inValue = new byte[4] { 1, 0, 0, 0 };
        sock.IOControl(IOControlCode.ReceiveAll, inValue, outValue);


        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[sock.ReceiveBufferSize];
                int count = sock.Receive(buffer);
                IPHeader hdr = new IPHeader(buffer, count);

                Console.WriteLine("IP : {0} -> {1} HeaderLen: {2} Byte TotalLen: {3} Byte", hdr.SourceAddress.ToString(), hdr.DestinationAddress, (Convert.ToUInt16(hdr.HeaderLength)) , (Convert.ToUInt16(hdr.TotalLength)));
                double volumn = (Convert.ToDouble(hdr.TotalLength));
                if (!IsPrivateIp(hdr.DestinationAddress.ToString()) || !IsPrivateIp(hdr.SourceAddress.ToString()))
                {
                    SumInternet += (double)volumn;
                }
                else
                {
                    LocalUsage += (double)volumn;
                }

                if (hdr.ProtocolType == Protocol.TCP)
                {
                    TCPHeader tcpheader = new TCPHeader(buffer, count);
                    Console.WriteLine("TCP :{0} -> {1} Len: {2} Byte", tcpheader.SourcePort, tcpheader.DestinationPort, tcpheader.HeaderLength + tcpheader.HeaderLength);
                }
                else if (hdr.ProtocolType == Protocol.UDP)
                {
                    UDPHeader tcpheader = new UDPHeader(buffer, count);
                    Console.WriteLine("UDP :{0} -> {1} Len: {2} Byte", tcpheader.SourcePort, tcpheader.DestinationPort, tcpheader.Length);

                }
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
                Console.WriteLine("\nInternet Usage :  {0:0.00} Byte == {1:0.00} Kb ", SumInternet, SumInternet / 1024);
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                Console.WriteLine("Local Usage :  {0:0.00} Byte == {1:0.00} Kb ", LocalUsage, LocalUsage / 1024);
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
                Console.WriteLine("All Use: {0:0.00} KB ", SumInternet + LocalUsage);
                TimeSpan ts = Time.Elapsed; 
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkCyan;
                Console.WriteLine("Spend Time: {0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:00}", ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds, ts.Milliseconds / 10);
                Console.Write("Internet Speed: {0:0.00} KB/S \n\n", SumInternet / ts.TotalSeconds);
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.Write("Error message :  {0} | Source: {1} ", ex.Message, ex.Source);
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is your question? If it is just "Will it work" why can't you run your program and see?

Comment: I can run it. And I see. but when I download a file (for example 1.5 Mb) only increase 100 or 200 kb in my program. I want to undrestand are raw socket show all packets(send and recive packet)? and my way is true?

Comment: Your program does not seem to be doing the actual download. Instead, it is intercepting inbound IP datagrams. Naturally, it will intercept only a subset of al inbound datagrams. In addition, I suspect that you are downloading the file using some other process, that that other process doesn't receive the intercepted datagrams, and as a result the downloaded data may be corrupted (it's possible the intercepted datagrams count as "lost" to the receiving process, in which case the data isn't corrupted, but just takes longer to download).

Comment: So what shoud I do? I want to calculate Internet broadbound and local broadbound separately.

Comment: *bandwidth or "download speed", not broadband. You can use `WebClient` to download a file from some server and time it using `Stopwatch` or something like this.